# Wordpress menu link to an iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I'm trying to add to my main menu a link that when user will click on it, it will open a frame, any idea how can I do that?I tried encores, but I couldn't add a target to the link in the menu.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411992/need-to-display-iframe-when-link-is-clicked-from-menu

Comment: but how can i add target to my menu link?

Comment: you can add a simple hack, in menu like this, http://path/to/playlist/1" target="playframe

Comment: It doesn't work. <a href="http://google.com;%20target=playframe" class="elementor-item">test link</a>

Comment: try removing semicolon after google.com

Comment: When i save it its remove the spaces and quotation marks